# sliding_window_view output dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a following array:

```
arr = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]
```

You can think of 0th dimension as time and 1st dimension of a given time step. I want to create a rolling window over it, i.e. sequences over time, say with a length of 3.

Calling

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (3,3))
```

results in

```
[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]]]
 [[[ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]]]
 [[[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]
   [12 13 14]]]]
```

as pretty much expected.

The only thing that confuses me is the shape of it, which is (3, 1, 3, 3), while I initially expected it to be (3, 3, 3). I suppose it might be about the axis along which the window is applied, yet I wasn't able to get the desired shape when tinkering with the axis parameter. Anyone can explain this? Is there any other way of getting 3-rank shape without resorting to reshaping of the result array?

Comment: In your case the shape ```(3, 1, 3, 3)``` corresponds to ```(num_windows_y, num_windows_x, window_size_y, window_size_x)```. When you have a 2D window you can move the window in 2 directions, but since you are only using the ```y``` direction, the ```x``` direction will be 1. You can look the source-code for the ```sliding_window```, it is just a user-friendly wrapper for ```as_strided```.

Comment: Reshape to (3,3,3) or slice with `[:,0]` (or `squeeze`) retains the `view` property, so aren't costly.  Sometimes reshaping a sliding window forces a copy, but simply removing the size 1 dimension doesn't.

Comment: As shown in the docs, slicing after `sliding_window_view` is normal, and expected if you want the full flexibility of `as_strided`.   It's intended as a safe, user-friendly wrapper to `as_strided`; in doing so it has to make some simplifications in the interface.  Tweaking the output is normal.

Answer (score 1):

[`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) will always return a view that is 2 dimensions above the window shape:

> The sliding window dimensions are inserted at the end, and the original dimensions are trimmed as required by the size of the sliding window

However, in this case, given that the number of windows on y will be 1 for this given window size, use axis=(0,0) and grab the first value from the returned array to get the desired results without an additional reshape or resort:

```
arr = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (3, 3), axis=(0, 0))[0]
```

`b`:

```
[[[ 0  3  6]
  [ 3  6  9]
  [ 6  9 12]]

 [[ 1  4  7]
  [ 4  7 10]
  [ 7 10 13]]

 [[ 2  5  8]
  [ 5  8 11]
  [ 8 11 14]]]
# b.shape (3, 3, 3)
```

---

```
sliding_window_view(arr, (3, 3), axis=(0, 0)).shape  # (1, 3, 3, 3)
sliding_window_view(arr, (3, 3), axis=(0, 0))[0].shape  # (3, 3, 3)
```